# How to list fields that are missing a trait and eliminate the ones that are not

Tags: sql, sql-server

First, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

I've tried searching but finding the right wording is probably what's failing me.

I'm trying to develop a query for my SQL class that returns a list of businesses `ResellerName` that have not sold 1 of 4 types of products`ProductCategoryKey`.

Like listing only the recipes that do not include carrots.

It requires me to join five tables to be able to link the `ResellerName` to the `ProductCategory`.

Current code looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    r.ResellerName  
FROM 
    (((DimReseller AS r
       FULL OUTER JOIN FactResellerSales AS rs ON r.ResellerKey = rs.ResellerKey)
     INNER JOIN DimProduct AS p ON rs.ProductKey = p.ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN DimProductSubcategory AS psc ON  p.ProductSubcategoryKey = psc.ProductSubcategoryKey)
INNER JOIN DimProductCategory AS pc ON psc.ProductCategoryKey = pc.ProductCategoryKey
ORDER BY r.ResellerName`
```

I'm lost as to what my `Where` clause should include to only list each company that has not sold a bike. My only thought is to try and make the Category 1 field a NULL field or something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to rewrite it is to use `LEFT JOIN` to find any matches on ProductCategoryKey, and `IS NULL` to remove the rows that include a match, something like;

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.ResellerName
FROM DimReseller AS r
LEFT JOIN FactResellerSales AS rs
  ON r.ResellerKey = rs.ResellerKey)
LEFT JOIN DimProduct AS p
  ON rs.ProductKey = p.ProductKey)
LEFT JOIN DimProductSubcategory AS psc
  ON  p.ProductSubcategoryKey = psc.ProductSubcategoryKey)
LEFT JOIN DimProductCategory AS pc
  ON  psc.ProductCategoryKey = pc.ProductCategoryKey
 AND pc.ProductCategoryKey IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
WHERE pc.ProductCategoryKey IS NULL
ORDER BY r.ResellerName
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Definitely makes more sense. Reading up Left Join more now to make sure I have them in the right order. Thank you!